# How to use buttons on "one IBAction for multiple buttons" in swift 2.x?

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I am making a calculator app on xcode7.x,swift 2.x.

Please tell how to display different numbers when using one IBAction for all numbers.

Comment: Please provide some more of code samples that you have written or links to resources you have explored or efforts made. It would help the people who wish to answer better understand your question

Answer (score 1):

Or programmatically for any number of buttons (note: this is Swift 3.0)

```
func setUp() {
    var button1, button2: UIButton!

    let buttons = [button1, button2]

    for i in 0..<buttons.count {
        buttons[i]?.tag = i
    }

    buttons.forEach({ $0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyClass.myAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside) })
}

func myAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(sender.tag)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create buttons in xib/storyboard
2. Set `tag` property for every digit (View section on the right)
   [image]
3. Ctrl-drag from any button to your class
4. Select IBAction in the popup and enter a name for
   [image: IBAction]
5. Implement the method:

```
@IBAction func digitPressed(button: UIButton) {
    print("digit pressed: \(button.tag)")
}
```

P.S. I would not recommend to use the same method for ALL your buttons, just for those, which are very close by their nature, like digits. If you also have + - * / buttons, you should add other IBActions for each of them.